# Creating a Noncopyable class and inherit into my class

Tags: c++, c++11, noncopyable

I am trying to create a non-copyable class and inherit it to myclass. Here's how the code looks:

```
template<class T>
struct NonCopyable
{
protected:
    NonCopyable() {}
private:
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable& x) = delete;  
    T& operator=(const T& x) = delete;
};
```

The delete allows a third mechanism through re-use of the delete keyword to define a function as “deleted.”

```
class Myclass : public RefCnt, private NonCopyable<Myclass>
{
    virtual unsigned int GetID() = 0;
    virtual bool Serialize() = 0;
};
```

Now when I try this,  I get an error on my VS 2010 as: 'NonCopyable' : pure specifier or abstract override specifier only allowed on virtual function.

The compiler is thinking I am trying to create a non virtual function as pure. Can somebody please explain why? I can solve the above problem, by removing "delete" keyword.

Comment: I suspect the answers is: `= delete` isn't yet supported by your compiler. I don't have VS 2010 to hand to confirm though.

Comment: I thought the same, but how do I verify that?

Comment: If you're using `= delete`, then just use it directly instead of inheriting from a class that uses it. And yes, VS10 doesn't support that.

Comment: Why is your `NonCopyable` a template? And as CatPP says, with C++11 and `delete` you don't really need this crutch of a construction anymore. It was only good when you didn't have a *semantic* way to express your intent of making a class noncopyable.

Comment: This question made me spawn this related one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458741

Comment: @Kerek SB, Yes you are right. I did that first and as it did not work, I tried isolating it by making a new templatized class. Finally, I got to know that VS10 doesnt support it. Thanks for all the inputs though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see from this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) that vs2010 does not support defaulted or deleted functions.  For that matter neither will vc11